# Error in Pandas 0.25, but was working in Pandas 0.20

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "SNOW Report with Plot.py", line 57, in <module>
    file1['Time in HH:MM:SS'] =  file1['Total outage duration'].apply(convert)
  File "D:\Softwares\Python\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 4038, in apply
    mapped = lib.map_infer(values, f, convert=convert_dtype)
  File "pandas\_libs\lib.pyx", line 2227, in pandas._libs.lib.map_infer
  File "SNOW Report with Plot.py", line 7, in convert
    return time.strftime("%H:%M:%S", time.gmtime(seconds))
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument
```

===========

when I try to execute the following function:

```
def convert(seconds):
    return time.strftime("%H:%M:%S", time.gmtime(seconds))


file1 = pd.read_excel('SNOW_RAW.xlsx')
mapping = pd.read_excel('Mapping.xlsx')

file1['Duplication_Check for INCC'] = file1['Number.1'].isin(file1['Number'])
file1['Time in HH:MM:SS'] =  file1['Total outage duration'].map(convert)
```

Total outage duration = in seconds (1000, 37, 200 etc values in that dataframe

Answer (score 0):

```
def convert(seconds):
    hours = seconds // (60*60)
    seconds %= (60*60)
    minutes = seconds // 60
    seconds %= 60
    return "%02i:%02i:%02i" % (hours, minutes, seconds)


def convert_to_strdate(create_date):
    # str = (create_date.split(" ")[0])
    # date_object = datetime.strptime(str, '%Y-%m-%d')
    return create_date.strftime("%d-%b")

def week_no(create_date):
    # str = (create_date.split(" ")[0])
    # date_object = datetime.strptime(str, '%Y-%m-%d')
    return create_date.strftime("Week %W")


def week_day(create_date):
    # str = (create_date.split(" ")[0])
    # date_object = datetime.strptime(str, '%Y-%m-%d')
    return create_date.strftime("%A")

def month(create_date):
    # str = (create_date.split(" ")[0])
    # date_object = datetime.strptime(str, '%Y-%m-%d')
    return create_date.strftime("%b'%y")
```